# XPath: How do I extract the text from almost equivalent html structure?

Tags: html, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to extract some news articles from a webpage, but the html structure changes for some of these articles.

In one case I have this:

[image]

and in another case I have this:

[image]

Is there a XPath I can use that could extract the full text on both cases?

**EDIT**

For the fist case I have tried this (using scrapy shell):

```
response.xpath('//*[@class="mioloNoticia"]/article/text()').extract()
```

which results in:

```
[u'\r\n      ',
 u'\r\n      ',
 u'\r\n      ',
 u'\r\n      ',
 u'\r\n      ',
 u'\r\n      ',
 u'Entendo as raz\xf5es dos defensores do acordo ortogr\xe1fico. Tamb\xe9m entendo as raz\xf5es pelas quais uma criatura acredita que \xe9 Napole\xe3o Bonaparte. ',
 u'Mais dif\xedcil de compreender \xe9 o motivo que leva uma classe pol\xedtica inteira a seguir com respeito Napole\xe3o Bonaparte. O problema do acordo nem sequer \xe9 t\xe9cnico ou jur\xeddico. Isso \xe9 \xf3bvio: qualquer um sabe que aquilo \xe9 uma aberra\xe7\xe3o lingu\xedstica (a grafia como mera transcri\xe7\xe3o fon\xe9tica?) e uma ilegalidade completa (lembrar as acrobacias jur\xeddicas que se fizeram sobre o texto original). Sem falar da ambi\xe7\xe3o autorit\xe1ria de submeter 300 milh\xf5es de falantes a um capricho racionalista. ',
 u'O problema do acordo \xe9 termos tido v\xe1rios governos que, reverentes e analfabetos, foram ratificando, modificando e legislando como se o acordo fosse mesmo para levar a s\xe9rio. Se Marcelo ajudar a acabar com esta farsa, a sua Presid\xeancia j\xe1 ter\xe1 valido a pena.']
```

and for the second case I have tried:

```
response.xpath('//*[@class="mioloNoticia"]/article/p/text()').extract()
```

which results in a better extraction:

```
[u'Os c\xe1lculos na ves\xedcula, os sintomas de um reumatismo que o atacava quando o Outono se aproximava ou a certeza de que o fim das coisas era inevit\xe1vel abriam-lhe a porta ao pessimismo em geral e \xe0 descren\xe7a no futuro \u2013 mas a vis\xe3o de um mundo encavalitado \xe0s costas do "progresso" era o aspecto mais penoso da exist\xeancia. A esta dist\xe2ncia, compreendo-o; ser "contra o progresso" \xe9 nos nossos dias um pecado capital, e resmungar contra "a criatividade" tornou-se uma apostasia definitiva e dram\xe1tica.',
 u'O "ser humano" est\xe1 condenado a acreditar na criatividade sem limites, na originalidade, no progresso, na mudan\xe7a e, finalmente, na ideia de que as coisas novas s\xe3o sempre superiores \xe0s antigas. Isto pode fazer confus\xe3o a um velho do Alto Minho, educado pela vida (e pelos desaires) a apreciar as coisas que permanecem e a desconfiar das inven\xe7\xf5es em que n\xe3o v\xea grande utilidade.',
 u'A minha sobrinha Maria Lu\xedsa \u2013 a eleitora esquerdista da fam\xedlia \u2013 j\xe1 foi uma sacerdotisa do Progresso (com mai\xfascula). Hoje, desconfia bastante da direc\xe7\xe3o que as coisas tomam, e o seu optimismo em rela\xe7\xe3o \xe0 esp\xe9cie humana \xe9 morigerado. Alimento a esperan\xe7a, dissimulada por muita cautela e certo tom de ironia, de v\xea-la feliz como Dona Ester, minha m\xe3e, gostava de ver felizes os seus filhos, espalhados sobre o areal da praia de Afife, respirando o iodo da tarde e abrigando-se do vento galego que descia pelo litoral. Os sucessos e insucessos dos \xfaltimos setenta anos ensinaram-me a desejar pouco, a aceitar a grandeza das coisas desconhecidas, a reler os livros que j\xe1 foram belos algum dia, a manter alguma f\xe9 numa ordem que comanda os planetas ou a solid\xe3o das dunas de Moledo. Ao mesmo tempo, esse ego\xedsmo n\xe3o faz mal aos outros. N\xe3o exige muito deles. N\xe3o lhes oferece demasiadas desilus\xf5es, nem utopias, nem promessas v\xe3s de um mundo perfeito. N\xe3o lhes alimenta a f\xe9 nas coisas imposs\xedveis que exigem que os outros mudem para que n\xf3s possamos satisfazer os desejos pessoais.',
 u'Esse mundo perfeito existe, sim \u2013 mas terminou h\xe1 muito, antes do progresso, da democracia e dos d\xe9fices da economia. Tamb\xe9m \xe9 preciso lembrar que n\xe3o se pode voltar atr\xe1s nem \xe9 poss\xedvel recuperar o tempo perdido. O que est\xe1 perdido, est\xe1 perdido. O que passou, passou h\xe1 muito.']
```

But I'm after a single XPath that could word for both cases.

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida, check my edit. Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a link so I can test it out?

Comment: Yes. This is from the first example:

http://www.cmjornal.xl.pt/opiniao/colunistas/joao_pereira_coutinho/detalhe/professor_martelo.html

and from the second:

http://www.cmjornal.xl.pt/opiniao/colunistas/antonio_sousa_homem/detalhe/nao_acreditar_no_progresso_nao_e_mau.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only different between different articles are plain text or text within

tags the xpath is quite simple

```
//article/text() | //article/p/text()
```

This will extract both whether one of them exists or both